# Maximum and minimum integer number of latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, gps

I'm developing an application where the user inputs latitude and longitude numbers in float type format.

I have to validate that the format of the numbers are correct.

My doubt is what is the maximun and minimum integer number on both latitude and longitude.

Let me give an example:

```
latitude:  <max/min>.666666
longitude: -<max/min>.666666
```

What are the correct `max` and `min` in both cases?

Comment: In degrees:  -90 to +90 latitude; -180 to +180 longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latitude is easy: -90 to +90.

Longitude can use one of two conventions: 0 to +360, or -180 to +180. You may want to handle both gracefully.

Comment: here is a nice explanation: 
 http://gis.humboldt.edu/OLM/Courses/old/GSP_101/01_IntroAndReivew/Presentation/Latitude_and_Longitude.html